# unpickle an object in a new context

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to unpickle an object that was pickled in an nbdev environment.  I still have the nbdev folder on the computer and am trying to unpickle the file in a separate .py file in a different project.

I tried adding the core.py file to the system path but to no avail.

```
import sys
filename = "object.pickle"
sys.path.append(r'/content/drive/My\ Drive/repos/frownyface/MagicalMusic/magicalMusic/core.py')
with open(filename, 'rb') as fs:
  loaded_model = pickle.load(fs) #<---- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magicalMusic.core'

loaded_model
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the problem with unpickling, it requires the module.  your ```sys.path.append..``` isn't going to help.  if you use sys.path.append, try ```sys.path.append(r'/content/drive/My\ Drive/repos/frownmyface/MagicalMusic')```

Comment: darn I tried the adjusted path, but same error.  to avoid this issue in the future is there a better package to use to save arbitrary objects?

Comment: not sure... but one thing you need to know about pickle is that it doesn't save function code..  from https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html